# Cannot activate triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am working on a triggered send for a customer.  I'm doing this in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud connector.  I'm having the hardest time getting a consistent understanding of what is needed to activate the send.

Some background:
We have a very complex trigger dispatcher that would preferable handle the invocation of the et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Object Name').  However, we quickly determined that the connector is looking through existing apex triggers and really wants to see that trig_ObjectName trigger exactly.

So we put this in place and included the invocation, but commented it out so we can keep the design consistent.

That worked at first and I could activate, but now it isn't working and I cannot re-activate after deactivating to edit the triggered send filter logic.  In fact, I even did the trigger verbatim and it still wouldn't activate.

Does anyone know the exact criteria marketing cloud is using to determine whether a valid trigger exists and that it's okay to activate the trigger?

Is it because the et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Object Name') class is being invoked in a separate location?

I'm really at a loss here.  We had this working well in staging but in production we could not get it to activate.

edit: for info - this was a different marketing cloud instance, and moving from a sandbox to production.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your staging and production environment?  Are these two different Salesforce Orgs or a sandbox and production environment?  Or are these different business units on the Marketing Cloud side?  I'm  trying to understand if your switch from staging to production evolved re-establishing the Marketing Cloud Connector?

Comment: When you activate a triggered send in Salesforce, it creates and/or re-publishes the Trigger Send Definition in Marketing Cloud.  I would suggest locating the Triggered Send Definition in Marketing Cloud and attempt to publish or start the trigger from there. Marketing Cloud may give you a more meaningfully error as to why it cannot be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the validation of the trigger code now looks for the api name of the object.

So I needed to update my trigger to have this line:

```
et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Object_API_Name__c');
```

Instead of:

```
et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Object Name');
```

Which is what I had working in my original implementation according.

Incidentally, while this code has to be present, it doesn't actually have to be the code that makes the trigger happen.  It can be commented out without a problem, it just has to be present.  I was able to successfully invoke the trigger from within a handler class called from a dispatcher, as long as this line is in the trig_ObjectName on Object_Name__c(after update, after insert){} trigger.  This allows us to at least be closer to our design, although it would be great if we could wrap the whole thing up.

So, marketing cloud must be doing a very specific match to a string to decide whether or not to activate the triggered send.  Kind of annoying, but I can see why they would want to.